# SELECT INTO not working

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I'd like to test a situation, but I need to add a dummy row of data to test the hypothesis.  So, according to [this mySQL manual page for SELECT INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html), my query is correct:

```
SELECT INTO courses.sections_rfip
  (SectionID, CourseID, SectionNumber, Term, Credits, CutOffDate, StartDate, EndDate, LastDateToWithDraw, ContinuousIntake, AcceptsRegistration, Fee, Instructor, SectionDescription, RegistrationRestrictions, MeetingTime, Notes, Active, Created, SetInactive)
  SELECT 3, 
         s.CourseID, 
         s.SectionNumber, 
         s.Term, 
         s.Credits, 
         s.CutOffDate, 
         s.StartDate, 
         s.EndDate, 
         s.LastDateToWithDraw, 
         s.ContinuousIntake, 
         s.AcceptsRegistration, 
         s.Fee, 
         s.Instructor, 
         s.SectionDescription, 
         s.RegistrationRestrictions, 
         s.MeetingTime, 
         s.Notes, 
         s.Active, 
         s.Created, 
         s.SetInactive 
    FROM courses.sections_rfip s
   WHERE s.sectionid = 1
```

But I get the following error msg:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO courses.sections_rfip
(SectionID, CourseID, SectionNumber, Term, Credits, ' at line 1"

So there's something rotten at the INTO, which isn't obvious to me why - help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try INSERT INTO instead: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

EDIT: Oops. Didn't realize that was the same page you had listed. However, as it says, use INSERT INTO since SELECT INTO (from Sybase) won't work.