# Complicated/Simple SQL Insert: adding multiple rows

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table connecting principals to their roles. I have come upon a situation where I need to add a role for each user. I have a statement `SELECT id FROM principals` which grabs a list of all the principals. What I want to create is something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO role_principal(principal_id,role_id)
VALUES(SELECT id FROM principals, '1');
```

so for each principal, it creates a new record with a role_id=1. I have very little SQL experience, so I dont know if I can do this as simply as I would like to or if there is some sort of loop feature in SQL that I could use.

Also, this is for a mySQL db (if that matters)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189810/mysql-5-1-35-select-into-not-working

Comment: Please stop thinking in terms of looping, looping is bad on databases, think interms of affecting sets of data instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `VALUES` keyword if you want to insert values directly. Omit it to use any `SELECT` (where column count and type matches) to get the values from.

```
INSERT INTO role_principal(principal_id,role_id)
    (SELECT id, 1 FROM principals);
```

Comment: When using INSERT . . . SELECT on most SQL systems, you omit the parens around the SELECT statement.  I think it's the same in MySQL, but not 100% sure.

Comment: I replaced 1 with (SELECT id FROM roles WHERE...) so that it could work for any role. But thank you for guiding me down the right path.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicates is useful to add a subquery :

INSERT INTO role_principal(principal_id,role_id)
(SELECT id, 1 FROM principals p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
 (SELECT * FROM role_principal rp WHERE rp.principal_id=p.id AND role_id=1)
)

Comment: Thanks for the additional answer. I know in my specific situation I wont have any duplicates but it is certainly good to know how I would handle that situation.