# IsNull() on bigint's min value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why does the following expression in SQL Server return `-9223372036854775808` and not `123`?

I am calling this from a stored proc where I can't pass null parameters

```
declare @t bigint;
set @t = -9223372036854775808;  --min value for bigint / long
select ISNULL(@t, 123)
```

Comment: You really asked that question?

Comment: Play nice boys.  Everyone who knows how to use the ISNULL() function had to learn it at some point.

Comment: @dave -- I agree with you that people should be nice. Although on the other hand, I would expect someone with 1881 reputation points to know how to look up and read the documentation for the function. I believe it is the first result returned by most search engines when searching for "ISNULL".

Comment: oh my...  
I upvoted all the answers by one.
For the answering people beeing realy merciful

Comment: I would like to delete this post :)

Comment: If it's any consolation, see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189810/mysql-5-1-35-select-into-not-working

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because:

```
IF @t IS NOT NULL
  PRINT @t
ELSE
  PRINT 123
```

Being negative doesn't mean the value is NULL.  NULL is the lack of any value at all.

Answer (score 4):

Because @t is not null.

What made you think that the most negative value for a bigint would be interpreted as null?

Comment: Good point, I don't know why I thought so and it was an impulse reaction to ask it on SO.

Answer (score 3):

The `ISNULL(@t, 123)` function returns 123 if @t is NULL, otherwise it returns @t.  You may want to do something like this.

```
NULLIF(@t, -9223372036854775808)
```

This will return NULL if @t equals -9223372036854775808.  NULLIF returns the first expression (@t) if the two expressions are not equal.

Comment: The ISNULL functin won't assign a 123 to @t if @t is NULL. The function ISNULL will return 123 if @t is NULL otherwise it returns the value of @t. The value of @t is unchanged.      see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Comment: your description of NULLIF is also incorrect. NULLIF returns the first expression if the two expressions are not equal. If the expressions are equal, NULLIF returns a null value of the type of the first expression. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx

Comment: Yep.  You're right.  I didn't explain them well.  I will correct.  Thanks @Adam.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what I think you want to achieve, try this:

```
declare @t bigint; 
set @t = -9223372036854775808;  --min value for bigint / long 
select ISNULL(NULLIF(@t, -9223372036854775808) , 123)
```

or this:

```
declare @t bigint; 
set @t = -9223372036854775808;  --min value for bigint / long 
select case @t when -9223372036854775808 then 123 else @t end
```

Answer (score 1):

@t is not null because you assigned it a value.  If you want ISNULL() to return 123, remove the assignment.

```
declare @t bigint;
select ISNULL(@t, 123)
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be assuming that `-9223372036854775808 IS NULL` which is incorrect. `ISNULL(@t, 123)` would only return NULL if `@t IS NULL` but it's not null since it has the value of `-9223372036854775808` which is non-NULL.

Answer (score 1):

ISNULL returns the first non-null value, they are both non-null (have value) so it returns the first one.