# SQLAlchemy 1.4 tutorial code "'Connection' object has no attribute 'commit'" error or does not commit changes

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql, sqlalchemy

Here is some custom code I wrote that I think might be problematic for this particular use case.

```
class SQLServerConnection:
    def __init__(self, database):
        ...
        self.connection_string = \
            "DRIVER=" + str(self.driver) +  ";" + \
            "SERVER=" + str(self.server) +  ";" + \
            "DATABASE=" + str(self.database) +  ";" + \
            "Trusted_Connection=yes;"   
        self.engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
            sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create(
                "mssql+pyodbc", \
                query={'odbc_connect': self.connection_string}
                                        )
                                              )
    # Runs a command and returns in plain text (python list for multiple rows)
    # Can be a select, alter table, anything like that
    def execute(self, command, params=False): 
        # Make a connection object with the server
        with self.engine.connect() as conn:
        
            # Can send some parameters along with a plain text query... 
                # could be single dict or list of dict
                # Doc: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/dbapi_transactions.html#sending-multiple-parameters
            if params:
                output = conn.execute(sqlalchemy.text(command,params))
            else:
                output = conn.execute(sqlalchemy.text(command))
            
            # Tell SQL server to save your changes (assuming that is applicable, is not with select)
            # Doc: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/dbapi_transactions.html#committing-changes
            try:
                conn.commit()
            except Exception as e:
                #pass
                warn("Could not commit changes...\n" + str(e))
           
            # Try to consolidate select statement result into single object to return
            try:
                output = output.all()
            except:
                pass
        return output
```

If I try:

```
cnxn = SQLServerConnection(database='MyDatabase')
cnxn.execute("SELECT * INTO [dbo].[MyTable_newdata] FROM [dbo].[MyTable] ")
```

or

```
cnxn.execute("SELECT TOP 0 * INTO [dbo].[MyTable_newdata] FROM [dbo].[MyTable] ")
```

Python returns this object without error, `<sqlalchemy.engine.cursor.LegacyCursorResult at 0x2b793d71880>`, but upon looking in MS SQL Server, the new table was not generated. I am not warned about the commit step failing with the `SELECT TOP 0` way; I am warned (`'Connection' object has no attribute 'commit'`) in the above way.

`CREATE TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE`, or `SELECT` (etc) appears to work fine, but `SELECT * INTO` seems to not be working, and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot further. Copy-pasting the query into SQL Server and running appears to work fine.

Comment: Does the [dbo].[MyTable_newdata] table already exist in your database? If so, does it have the same exact column headings/types from [dbo].[MyTable]?

Comment: `self.server` resolves appropriately. I use the same value with `CREATE TABLE` commands and it works as expected. I mean browsing in the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio application.

Comment: No, [dbo].[MyTable_newdata] does not exist either before or after either of the `cnxn.execute()` commands above. In fact, if I do produce it in SSMS, SQLAlchemy will complain that that table already exists! Essentially what I am trying to do in this particular case is duplicate the structure of [dbo].[MyTable], but the problem extends to other cases where I might want to do a `SELECT INTO` situation.

Comment: Rather than trying to insert it into the database, try cnxn.execute("SELECT * INTO ##MyTableNew FROM [dbo].[MyTable] ") to see if it can create a table in the temp database, first?

Comment: I'd have to think about this more, but I believe self.engine.connect() closes the session immediately after the execute method? So the temp table would be deleted immediately? This particular class I wrote doesn't work in sending two ;-separated SQL commands at once. No errors are printed if I try inserting into a temp table, though.

Comment: *upon looking in MS SQL Server, the new table was not generated* ... if using Management Studio (an IDE to MSSQL), did you refresh the table list? Try checking table existence with SQL: `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`. (Do not change `TABLE_NAME` which is an actual column of that system table).

Comment: Right, MyTable_newdata will not show up in the side panel after refreshing, it says not found if I do `SELECT * FROM MyTable_newdata` and it does not appear as a record of `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`. If I run the exact same query from the python code (`SELECT * INTO [dbo].[MyTable_newdata] FROM [dbo].[MyTable]`) in the SSMS application, everything appears to work as expected and it will show up in all of those methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the introduction to the 1.4 tutorial [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/index.html#a-note-on-the-future):

> A Note on the Future
>
> This tutorial describes a new API that’s released in SQLAlchemy 1.4 known as 2.0 style. The purpose of the 2.0-style API is to provide forwards compatibility with SQLAlchemy 2.0, which is planned as the next generation of SQLAlchemy.
>
> In order to provide the full 2.0 API, a new flag called future will be used, which will be seen as the tutorial describes the Engine and Session objects. These flags fully enable 2.0-compatibility mode and allow the code in the tutorial to proceed fully. When using the future flag with the create_engine() function, the object returned is a subclass of sqlalchemy.engine.Engine described as sqlalchemy.future.Engine. This tutorial will be referring to sqlalchemy.future.Engine.

That is, it is assumed that the engine is created with

```py
engine = create_engine(connection_url, future=True)
```

You are getting the "'Connection' object has no attribute 'commit'" error because you are creating an old-style Engine object.

You can avoid the error by adding `future=True` to your `create_engine()` call:

```py
        self.engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
            sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create(
                "mssql+pyodbc",
                query={'odbc_connect': self.connection_string}
            ),
            future=True
        )
```

Comment: Note that this does not apparently work with pandas at this time. So my workaround was to make two separate engine object attributes: one with future=True, one with future=False. Any time I used pandas read_sql function or dataframe.to_sql method I would use the v1 engine. In the execute method I write above, I use v2.0.

Comment: Your code could also use `with self.engine.begin() as conn:` which will automatically commit if no errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this recipe](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/SelectInto) instead:

```py
#!python
from sqlalchemy.sql import Select
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles

class SelectInto(Select):
    def __init__(self, columns, into, *arg, **kw):
        super(SelectInto, self).__init__(columns, *arg, **kw)
        self.into = into

@compiles(SelectInto)
def s_into(element, compiler, **kw):
    text = compiler.visit_select(element)
    text = text.replace('FROM', 
                'INTO TEMPORARY TABLE %s FROM' % 
                element.into)
    return text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sqlalchemy.sql import table, column

    marker = table('marker', 
        column('x1'),
        column('x2'),
        column('x3')
    )

    print SelectInto([marker.c.x1, marker.c.x2], "tmp_markers").\
            where(marker.c.x3==5).\
            where(marker.c.x1.in_([1, 5]))
```

This needs some tweaking, hence it will replace all subquery selects as select INTOs, but test it for now, if it worked it would be better than raw text statments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this from [this answer by @Michael Berkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287698/introduction-of-sql-select-into-why-will-it-not-run/9287734#9287734):

```sql
INSERT INTO assets_copy
  SELECT * FROM assets;
```

The answer states that MySQL documentation states that `SELECT * INTO` isn't supported.

Comment: This question concerns Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL.